# Why "Do not disturb" bug will fix itself on Jan 7th?

Tags: ios, bug

Just pure curiosity! Last year, the bug is fixed on Jan 2nd too. Both are those days are Monday. Is this just coincidence?

What kind of programming mistake that lead to this bug?

Comment: Of what I read, it's because next week starts on monday 7 and the current week is sharerd on 2012 and 2013 but still considered as week 1 on calendars.

Comment: this is so so lame, how much cash have apple got and they can't fix a bug any script kiddy could

Comment: I would really like to know an 'official' answer to this too

Comment: Speculation about why Apple did something is off-topic here. Questions about how to work around a bug or the user-end points of a bug are on topic here and [pretty well documented by Apple as well](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4510). You might see about asking on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) if you have date code that is buggy or [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) if you want to discuss what class of code is susceptible to bugs of this nature, but we don't host programming questions here.